# Is it possible to get windows service password with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-services

With Powershell is it possible to get a window service's password? The windows service is setup to run under an AD domain account.

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: To see if a way exists..

Comment: These are protected in the registry with encryption. Yes they are stored, but no they are not easily obtainable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it have to be possible, Passwords for Windows services are stored in the registry under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\_SC_<ServiceName>
```